# As a MSc. in Civil Engineering what are my chances to find a fully funded Ph.D position in Bioinformatics?

Tags: phd, career-path, bioinformatics

Having graduated with sub 3.0 GPA BSc and MSc with a 3.5 GPA in civil engineering and despite currently working professionally, I am considering a possible career change into bioinformatics. Continuing in my current field of expertise makes obvious sense, however, my gut feeling draws me more to bioinformatics. Considering these conditions what is the possibility of getting a bioinformatics phd position in either the USA or Canada as an international student seeking full funding?